# Android WebView and audio output on earpiece

Tags: android, webview, webrtc, android-audiomanager

How can I force an Android WebView which loads a webrtc page to use the "earpiece" as default audio output instead of the loudspeaker?

I tried this code, but the sound keeps coming out of the speakers, not the earpiece:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
```

I also tried to change the second line to:

```
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
```

Of course, I have this in the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

I also tried this other code as suggested elsewhere:

```
this.player = new MediaPlayer();
player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);
```

None of these solutions send the sound out the earpiece.

What is the correct way to use the earpiece in case of a WebView?

Thanks

Comment: Have you found any solutions?

Comment: possible duplicate from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69336155/android-webview-play-audio-through-earpiece-or-bluetooth/69386868#69386868